# APC Back-UPS ES 500 stopped working

Tags: ups

Last night I plugged an electric heater into one of the 3 battery back up outlets on my UPS. After about 10 minutes all 3 stopped working. The other 3 outlets that are surge protection only still work. Another thing I have noticed is that every time I turn it on there is no power in those 3 outlets for the first 5-8 seconds, after that I hear a click and power comes on and after another 5-8 seconds I hear another click and the power is off and never comes back. The other 3 outlets work just fine.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: If you still have the heater plugged in, unplug it, let the battery recharge overnight, and then see if it works normally.  If the recurring problem you describe was after unplugging the heater, see Mekki MacAulay's answer.  BTW, you can expect similar issues plugging a laser printer into the battery backup outlets.

Answer (score 4):

Electric heaters draw a LOT of electricity.  The APC UPS ES 500 is rated for 500VA or around 300 watts.  Your electric heater probably tried to draw 1000 watts or more and blew a capacitor or exceeded the trip circuit's ability to disconnect without bridging damage in the UPS.

The surge protection outlets aren't connected to the battery, so they probably were on a different circuit path and weren't blown.

Unless you are familiar enough with electronics to open up the UPS, test the components until you locate the bad ones, desolder them, resolder them with replacements, test, and be sure that you don't connect anything that depends on the quality of your work, there's no "fix" for this.

The battery backup side should be treated as dead.  Don't plug any valuable electronics into it.  I'd treat even the surge protection only outlets as iffy.  Replacing the device entirely is your safest option to keep protecting your expensive devices.